# Xamarin mobile app deployment to phone not working outside of debug

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment

I created a simple Xamarin ANDROID App. I set up my phone to development mode and deployed my app to the phone via USB.
The app continues to work on the phone as a regular app.

I then created a Xamarin MOBILE App which was more complex. I deployed it to my android phone via Visual Studio debug mode as with my previous app and it ran perfectly. But when I attempt to run the app directly from my phone, it won’t run. The first screen partially loads without anything on it and then disappears. My phone puts a message up saying that my app keeps stopping and would I like to close the app. I make use of a file placed in Assets. Might this be an issue when not debugging from the computer?

Might there be a difference between deploying a xamarin android app and a xamarin mobile app.

A minor thing is that it has added the name ‘.droid’ to the name of my app which I would like to get rid of.

I am new to deploying apps to a phone

Comment: have you checked the device logs for information about why the app is stopping?

Comment: Please show us some error messages or errors from the logs.

Comment: Never happened to me, but maybe you can do a quick test: try to create an apk using the "Archive..." option in the "Build" menu. If everything goes right, you end up with the installer file which can be used to manually install your app in the phone. If it works this way, then you can assume that there is no problem related to your code, and the problem may be your configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it thanks to your helpful prompts.
I looked at the error logs and the error was ‘FATAL’ in a mono dll. This was indirectly helpful in that I knew it wasn’t the logic in my code.
I also made the discovery that running my app directly in the emulator also failed in the same manner as on my phone. I also ruled out that it might be an issue with transferring an asset -a file the my app uses- as I bypassed using the asset.
(Running my app via visual studio in both the emulator and my phone worked perfectly.)

I then decided to re-house my forms and classes in a new template as I suspected it was corruption in some xml configuration setting that didn’t bother Visual Studio. This worked great and the app now runs stand alone on the phone (and emulator).

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer, which will help more people.